# System.data.linq namespace not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, smartphone

I have visual studio 2010 express for windows phone installed on my system and i am not able to find System.data.linq namespace in references so i tried to download the the dll and copy in the C:\Program Files(x86)\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone  location but it is saying it is a dll not built for windows phone can anyone help to add the correct dll as the reference..? thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the latest SDK installed? `System.Data.Linq` is only available in the 7.1 version!

Comment: Ya recently only i downloaded from microsofts site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. Your project should be minimum windows phone 7.1 version. Look what is written in your csproj file. There should be: `<TargetFrameworkProfile>WindowsPhone71</TargetFrameworkProfile>`
but no 
`<TargetFrameworkProfile>WindowsPhone</TargetFrameworkProfile>`

In my sutuation there was written just WindowsPhone and I corrected it to WindowsPhone71 and I got System.Data.Linq and mscorlib.extenstion libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You may have to import the reference manually.

Mine is located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\system.data.linq.dll
```

That should fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i cant find the folder Windows phone71 also i installed sdk directly from microsoft site

Comment: Do you have the mango update? I believe LINQ only became available then. Google leads me [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570).